# Sargan test results = 1 in system GMM

Tags: r, statistical-significance, generalized-moments

I am having difficulties understanding my diagnostic test results for my twoways effects two-step model system GMM, which I performed in R.

The results of my Sargan test (test for overidentification restrictions) are:

```
Sargan test: chisq(246) = 92.2451 (p-value = 1)
```

I have a large unbalanced dataset of 40.000 observations, a time of 20 years and 10 variables in my analysis.

What does the value of 1 mean?